# Arraylist custom location

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have an arraylist and I want to update specific item.I am adding data to list with this line:

```
randomsList.add(new Random(result.get(i).getAsJsonObject(),0));
```

This is adding datas to 0,1,2,3,4... locations so when I try to update an item I don't know which object is where.

I am updating data with this line:

```
randomsList.set(position,new Random(user,1));
```

I think if I use the custom numbers for location I can update specific item.My prototype:

```
randomsList.add({USER_ID},new Random(result.get(i).getAsJsonObject(),0));
```

And if I want to update it then I use this line:

```
randomsList.set({USER_ID},new Random(user,1));
```

Is this a good approach ? If your answer is no,how should be ?

**P.S.** : *I am using this arraylist with an adapter*

Comment: You should create a [`Map`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html), instead of an `ArrayList`

Comment: I am using this with an Android adapter

Comment: @SerkaySarıman you can create an Android adapter (extending BaseAdapter) which uses a Map as the underlying datasource.

Comment: @ataulm Can you give a small sample for this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @itachiuchiha mentions, you should use a Map. The "custom numbers" you mention are your *key* (integers), and the value is the `Random` object.

As an aside, in response to your comment, below is an example of an Android `Adapter` that uses a Map as the underlying datasource.

```
public class RandomsAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Map<Integer, Random> randoms;

    public RandomsAdapter(Map<Integer, Random> randoms) {
        this.randoms = randoms;
    }

    public void updateRandoms(Map<Integer, Random> randoms) {
        this.randoms = randoms;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return randoms.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Random getItem(int position) {
        return randoms.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // we won't support stable IDs for this example
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;
        if (view == null) {
            view = createNewView();
        }
        update(view, songs.get(position));
        return view;
    }

    private View createNewView() {
        // TODO: create a new instance of your view and return it
        return null;
    }

    private void update(View view, Random random) {
        // TODO: update the rest of the view
    }

}
```

Note the `updateRandoms(Map<Integer, Random> randoms)` method.

While you could expose a method in the adapter to update a single entry in the Map, it shouldn't be the responsibility of the Adapter to handle modifications to the map. I prefer passing the entire map again - it could still be a reference to the same object, but the Adapter doesn't know or care; it just knows: "my underlying datasource has been changed/modified, I need to tell my observers that they should refresh their views by calling `notifyDataSetChanged()`".

Alternatively, you could call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on the adapter externally when you modify the underlying Map (this tells the ListView that its data is out of date and to request its views from the adapter again).

Comment: Thank you so much,how can I get an item using map value ?

Comment: Look up the map class on Google.

Comment: The type BaseAdapter is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <MainActivity.Random> I am getting this error. For this line :private static class RandomsAdapter extends BaseAdapter<Random>

Comment: sorry, remove the type args

Comment: I researched the internet but I can't find how to use this.Please give me an example I need this

Comment: See http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Map.html. You can use put and get methods to change your Map. One possible implementation of Map interface is HashMap. You can instantiate it like HashMap<Integer, Random> randomsHashMap = new HashMap<Integer, Random>();, in your case.

Comment: How can I use this as android adapter ? Example how can I add data to this adapter?

Comment: @SerkaySarıman you edit/create a dataset - the Map. Then in your adapter, you call `updateRandoms(myMapOfRandoms);`