# Arrayadapter custom id

Tags: android

I have an arrayadapter extending from baseadapter and using it with an arraylist for store data.I need to update individual item.So I need to give an id for each item when adding to arraylist.Then I will update it with `set` method like this:

```
randomsList.set(position,new Random(user,1));
```

I mean I need a position value.Somebody said you need do implement of `map` for this.But I don't know how can I do it.I need an example.

This is my class:

```
private static class Randoms{
    private List<Random> randoms=null;

    public Randoms(List<Random> randoms) {
        this.randoms=randoms;
    }
    public Random get(int position) {
        return randoms.get(position);
    }
    public int size() {
        return randoms.size();
    }
}
```

And this is my adapter:

```
private static class RandomsAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
    private Randoms randoms;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private Context context;
    private RandomsAdapter(Context context,Randoms randoms) {
        this.randoms=randoms;
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.context=context;
    }
    public void updateRandoms(Randoms randoms) {
        this.randoms=randoms;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return randoms.size();
    }
    @Override
    public Random getItem(int position) {
        return randoms.get(position);
    }
    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }
    public View getView(int position,View convertView,ViewGroup parent) {

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to use the position of the item in the list as the id value of the item:

You can create a wrapper class for `Random` that will hold the `Random` object and its id.

```
class RandomWrapper {
    private Random rand;
    private int id;
    RandomWrapper(Random rand, int id) {
        this.rand = rand;
        this.id = id;
    }
    public Random getRand() {
        return this.rand;
    }
    public int getID() {
        return this.id;
    }
}
```

This way, if you want to access your `Random`, call `yourRandomWrapper.getRand()` and if you want to get the id, call `yourRandomWrapper.getID()`

So, for example, adding 5 items to your list:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    randomsList.add(new RandomWrapper(yourRandomObj, i));
}
```

If you want to generate a unique ID for your objects, you can use the `java.util.UUID` class. If you are interested in how it works, you can check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/325457/3928341) or the [Oracle Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25715154/arraylist-custom-location/25715387 Can you review this ?